# Conditional SQL Query in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to HIbernate Framework and picked up a sample code from internet to start with. Here is sample code

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Contact.class);
return hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria, start, limit);
```

The above code is returning a List with all the records from database.
My question is what if i want to write a conditional query like

```
select CONTACT_ID,CONTACT_EMAIL,CONTACT_NAME,CONTACT_PHONE
from testtable
where   CONTACT_NAME='Contact12';
```

Comment: Some things need to be learnt, seriously, and not just by picking examples found on some random site. Hibernate is one of them. Read the documentation: http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/

Comment: BTW, HibernateTemplate shouldn't be used anymore. This is also written in the javadoc of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example you can use (if the property is called `contactName`)

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contactName", "Contact12"));
```

But in general you should use other methods of `Restrictions` to achieve this.